# How to edit layout of category?

Tags: joomla3.0

How can I edit the layout of category.

I am unable to find the solution. I need to edit it via Control Panel, not using direct file editing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To edit the layout of category,  Edit the menu item that is linked to that category. In the menu item edit page, you will find all the option for changing category layout.

[image]

Also you can change the Global options in Content > Categories page then click on the options button to see all category options.

Comment: I did not find there any layout to edit. Category and Blog Layout are missing.